Efficient way to hash the contents of a hash table
I've searched the internet and apparently in 2024 it's very rare to want to record the state of a hash table, in order to later see if it has changed.
If it were any other sort of data object, like a list, I'd just use (sxhash LIST), so I naively tried (sxhash TABLE), but that won't work since only the memory address of the whole table affects the result.
Demonstration:
(setq tbl (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
(setq other-tbl (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

;; Returns nil because the values aren't compared, just the memory addresses
(equal tbl other-tbl) ;; => nil
(= (sxhash tbl) (sxhash other-tbl)) ;; => nil

;; Modifying the table does not change its sxhash
(sxhash tbl) ;; => 33360399514540
(puthash "foo" "bar"  tbl)
(sxhash tbl) ;; => 33360399514540

I've come up with a solution, below, but I'm left wondering if there is any kind of standard practice here, or if someone has a clever trick to make it do less work.
(defun hash-the-table (tbl)
  "Hash the values in table TBL and return sum."
  (let ((sum 0))
    (maphash (lambda (_k v)
               (setq sum (+ sum (sxhash v))))
             tbl)
    sum))

(defun tables-equal (one other)
  (= (hash-the-table one) (hash-the-table other)))

;; Demonstration: it works
(setq tbl (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
(setq other-tbl (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
(puthash "foo" "bar" tbl)
(puthash "foo" "bar" other-tbl)
(tables-equal tbl other-tbl) ;; => t



If it were any other sort of data object, like a list, I'd just use (sxhash LIST), so I naively tried (sxhash TABLE), but that won't work since only the memory address of the whole table affects the result.

Apparently hashing hashtables just wasn't implemented. I think such functional may be added to Emacs (but you'd have to discuss with Emacs maintainers to be sure). Looking at source code, I see for example that lists traversal is supported by sxhash, so lack of hashtables traversal is probably just an omission.

I've come up with a solution, below, but I'm left wondering if there is any kind of standard practice here, or if someone has a clever trick to make it do less work.

There isn't much to improve. Hashtable as a data structure in general is implemented by pre-allocating a buffer much larger than the amount of elements, so explicit traverse of existing elements would be the most efficient way to get complete hash of the table. The only improvement I can think of is if the API provided a way to retrieve the element hash. You can make a feature request for that.
However, I should note that your implementation via hash values summation likely increases the risk of collisions. I can't prove that offhand, but I vaguely remember that hash calculations reduce collisions risk via tricks with prime numbers, and the overflow should be handled via this hash-specific algorithm. Simple summation won't work too well.
For sxhash you'd need to replace summation with sxhash_combine, but unfortunately as of writing the words this function is not accessible in ELisp. If you need it, I guess that warrants a feature request (or you can write a C module and load it into your Emacs. Or you can even replicate it in ELisp but I think it might be slow).
